# Merge Two Sorted Lists leetcode

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain this code to me? I have no idea what's going on after the while statement. This is from Merge Two Sorted Lists problem from leetcode and someone else solved it using this code (JavaScript). I just want to understand what's going on. I have little understanding on linked list... Help...

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
/**
 * @param {ListNode} list1
 * @param {ListNode} list2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var mergeTwoLists = function(list1, list2) {
    let dummyHead = new ListNode();
    let tail = dummyHead;
    let curr1 = list1;
    let curr2 = list2;
    
    while(curr1 !== null && curr2 !== null){
        
        if(curr1.val < curr2.val){
            tail.next = curr1;
            curr1 = curr1.next;
        }
        else{
            tail.next = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        }
        
        tail = tail.next;
    }
    
    if(curr1 !== null){
        tail.next = curr1;
    }
    if(curr2 !== null){
        tail.next = curr2;
    }
    
    return dummyHead.next;
}
let list1 = [1,2,4]
let list2 = [1,3,4]

mergeTwoLists(list1, list2);
```

Result should be: [1,1,2,3,4,4]

Comment: I'd suggest trying this one out physically with some playing cards. The algorithm is very intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

(Singly) Linked List is a value (e.g List1.val = 9001) and a pointer to the next Node in the list -- if it exists, otherwise it's null.

So:

`{ Node (0) aka Head val: 5 next: (pointer to Node (1)) }`

`{ Node (1) val: 12 next: (pointer to Node (2)) }`

`{ Node (2) ... Node (N)}`

`{ Node (N) aka Tail val: 9001    next: null (no next node, this is the tail) }`

Question asks you two merge two sorted linked lists together into one (new) list. Start:

Tail: `{}`

Compare `{ List1 Node(1) val: 1}` &&  `{ List2 Node(1) val: 3}`
Since List1 value is less, we will update the tail to point to this value.

Tail `{next: {List1 Node(1) val: 1}}`

Then we update the current list1 node position here: curr1 = curr1.next.
so = next node on List1 changes from `{List1 Node(1) val: 1}` to `{List1 Node(2) val: 2}`

then update tail to move over a node (so we can add a fresh node in the next loop) in `tail = tail.next;`

Tail: `{Node(1) val: 1, next: null}`

Then reset loop:

Compare `{ List 1 Node(2) val: 2} { List2 Node(1) val: 3}`
curr1.val is less than curr2.val, repeat same process as above.
Tail: `{Node(1) val: 1, next: { List 1 Node(2) val: 2} }`

Update curr1 to point to Node 3: `{List1 Node(3) val: 4}`

then update tail pointer so we are on the node we just added:
`{ List 1 Node(2) val: 2} next: null`

and repeat the loop again.

Hopefully that helps.